# convert below sql statement to linq using lambda operator

Tags: linq-to-entities

I am trying to apply self join in linq. sql statement is as below :

TableEmployee (ID,EmployeeName,EmployeeManager)//table structure

```
select a.EmployeeName from TableEmployee a 
inner join TableEmployee b on a.EmployeeManager=b.EmployeeName
```

Basicaly I want to ensure if EmployeeManager exist in table. Please convert this to linq using lambda operators.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `EmployeeManager` exists? Whether a given employee has a manager or the given employee is a manager or something else?

Answer (score 0):

For your query, it should be

```
List<TableEmployee> list = (from em in TableEmployee 
join en in TableEmployee on em.EmployeeManager equals en.EmployeeName
select em).ToList();
```

Can you try this with lambda ?

```
TableEmployee.Where(x => x.EmployeeManager == x.EmployeeName).ToList();
```